# Libgdx: Save and Load

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Could anyone give me any idea or suggestion on how to save and load game states in Libgdx, because I'm trying to create a game which allows a player to save and load their game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modeled my game persistence after this tutorial, its working well for me. [Check it out.](https://code.google.com/p/steigert-libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tyrian-game/src/com/blogspot/steigert/tyrian/services/ProfileService.java?r=19)

It persists files in JSON format, and encodes the string into base-64 giving a bit of obscurity if anyone tries to alter your game files.